# FizzBuzz solved by neural network

Tags: c, ruby-on-rails

I wrote a very simple AI in C and connected it to the web through Ruby on Rails.  It learns the fizzbuzz problem.  I'm writing this because I'm back on the job market after 20 years.  Of course, github didn't even exist back then.  So, now the job hunt environment is totally  different and I don't have the assets recruiters are looking for.  So, I'm begging for help.  I'm asking for a code review of this and any advice you guys have for me.  https://github.com/rickcockerham/fizzbuzz-ai
Thanks,
Rick

```
// Fbai class.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
// A C program that learns the Fizz Buzz problem.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
// I used my neural network code that I downloaded years ago and modified.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
// I have simplified the neural network code to make it only has complicated as                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
// it needs to be to solve this simple problem.  One hidden layer and four separate                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
// networks is all it takes to solve the FB problem in 5-10 learning runs.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
//################################################################################                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ruby.h>

//nn constants                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
double Error, eta = 0.1; // a very slow learning rate                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
double alpha = 0.90, smallwt = 0.2;
#define PASSES 1 //passes per training run.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
#define NUMPATTERNS 100 // 1-100                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
#define NUMHIDDEN 1 // hidden layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#define NUMINPUTS 1 //number of inputs. In this case it's just a single integer.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
#define NNS 4 // one neural network output per norm,fizz,buzz,fizzbuzz                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
double expected[NNS][NUMPATTERNS+1]; //holds the test data.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

// The weights and outputs of the neural network.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
double WeightIH[NNS][NUMINPUTS+1][NUMHIDDEN+1];//2. bias and input                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
double WeightHO[NNS][NUMHIDDEN+1];
double SumH[NNS][NUMPATTERNS+1][NUMHIDDEN+1], Hidden[NNS][NUMPATTERNS+1][NUMHIDDEN+1];
double SumO[NNS][NUMPATTERNS+1], Output[NNS][NUMPATTERNS+1];
double DeltaO[NNS], SumDOW[NNS][NUMHIDDEN+1], DeltaH[NNS][NUMHIDDEN+1];
double DeltaWeightIH[NNS][NUMINPUTS+1][NUMHIDDEN+1], DeltaWeightHO[NNS][NUMHIDDEN+1];

// The names of each network.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
#define NORM 0
#define FIZZ 1
#define BUZZ 2
#define FIZZBUZZ 3

void train();
int gotest(int);
void init_ai();

//########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
//random double.  I would normally use lib sodium for better random.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
double randd() {
  return rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
}

//################################################################################                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
// Ruby - C interface code.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
// These functions are exposed to Ruby.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

VALUE rb_fbai;

VALUE gotrain(VALUE self) {
  train();//run a single training epoch.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  return self;
}

VALUE reinit(VALUE self) {
  init_ai();// clear the weights and start over.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  return self;
}

VALUE valueat(VALUE self, VALUE testnum) {
  int testx = NUM2INT(testnum); //convert VALUE to int                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

  int returnval = gotest(testx);// get the AI output for this int.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

  return INT2NUM(returnval);//convert it back to a VALUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}

// define interface methods between Ruby and C                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
void Init_fbai() {
  rb_fbai = rb_define_class("Fbai", rb_cObject);
  rb_define_method(rb_fbai, "gotrain", gotrain, 0);
  rb_define_method(rb_fbai, "valueat", valueat, 1);
  rb_define_method(rb_fbai, "reinit", reinit, 0);

  init_ai();
}

//################################################################################                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
// the patterns are the training data.  It's an array of 3 values 0 if it's just x, 1 if it's %3, 2 if it's %5, and 3 if it's %3&%5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
// these are stored in three values for three sets of training patterns.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

void patterns() {

  memset(expected, 0.0, NNS * NUMPATTERNS+1); // all zeros first                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

  for(int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {

    if(x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0) {
      expected[FIZZBUZZ][x] = 1.0; // set expexted[3][x] = 1.0 the rest are zeros.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    } else if(x % 5 == 0) {
      expected[BUZZ][x] = 1.0;
    } else if(x % 3 == 0) {
      expected[FIZZ][x] = 1.0;
    } else {
      expected[NORM][x] = 1.0;
    }
  }
}

//################################################################################                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
// clear all the weights and randomize them to learn the problem or learn it again.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
void init_ai() {
  int nn,hid,i;

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  // init nn                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

  memset(Output, 0.0, NNS * (NUMPATTERNS+1)); // all zeros for outputs.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  memset(Hidden, 0.0, NNS * (NUMPATTERNS+1) * (NUMHIDDEN+1));

  for(nn = 0; nn < NNS; nn++) { // loop through all neural nets                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

    for( hid = 0 ; hid < NUMHIDDEN ; hid++ ) {    /* initialize WeightIH and DeltaWeightIH */
      for( i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        DeltaWeightIH[nn][i][hid] = 0.0 ;
        WeightIH[nn][i][hid] = 2.0 * ( randd() - 0.5 ) * smallwt ;
      }
    }
    /* initialize WeightHO and DeltaWeightHO */
    for( hid = 0 ; hid < NUMHIDDEN ; hid++ ) {
      DeltaWeightHO[nn][hid] = 0.0 ;
      WeightHO[nn][hid] = 2.0 * ( randd() - 0.5 ) * smallwt ;
    }

  }
  patterns();
}

//#############################################                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
// Returns -1 if the output is wrong otherwise it will return 0-3 as the output.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
int gotest(int x) {
  double max = 0.0;
  int nn, maxx = 0;
  int correct = 0;
  for(nn = 0; nn < NNS; nn++) {
    if(Output[nn][x] > max) {
      max = Output[nn][x];
      maxx = nn;
      if(1.0 == expected[nn][x]) correct = 1;
    }
  }
  return (1 == correct ? maxx : -1);
}


//################################################################################                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
//################################################################################                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
//################################################################################                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
// training run for the AI.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
// This code was downloaded from the internet many years ago and modifed for my other AI project ai-stocktrading.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
// I've simplifed it for this small demo.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
void train() {

  int hid, nn, p, epoch;

  for(nn = 0; nn < NNS; nn++) { // loop through both neural nets                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

    for( epoch = 0 ; epoch < PASSES ; epoch++) {
      Error = 0.0;

      for( p = 1 ; p < NUMPATTERNS+1 ; p++ ) {    /* repeat for all the training patterns */

        for( hid = 1 ; hid <= NUMHIDDEN ; hid++ ) {    /* compute hidden unit activations */
          SumH[nn][p][hid] = WeightIH[nn][0][hid] ;// bias against input 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

          SumH[nn][p][hid] += expected[nn][p] * WeightIH[nn][1][hid]; //double np is the input 1-100                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
          Hidden[nn][p][hid] = 1.0/(1.0 + exp(-SumH[nn][p][hid])) ;
        }


        /* compute output unit activations and errors */
        SumO[nn][p] = WeightHO[nn][0]; // bias                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        for( hid = 1 ; hid <= NUMHIDDEN ; hid++ ) {
          SumO[nn][p] += Hidden[nn][p][hid] * WeightHO[nn][hid] ;
        }

        // Sigmoidal Outputs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        Output[nn][p] = 1.0/(1.0 + exp(-SumO[nn][p]));

       //Sigmoidal Outputs, SSE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        DeltaO[nn] = (expected[nn][p] - Output[nn][p]) * Output[nn][p] * (1.0 - Output[nn][p]) ;

        for( hid = 1 ; hid <= NUMHIDDEN ; hid++ ) {    /* 'back-propagate' errors to hidden layer */
          SumDOW[nn][hid] = WeightHO[nn][hid] * DeltaO[nn];
          DeltaH[nn][hid] = SumDOW[nn][hid] * Hidden[nn][p][hid] * (1.0 - Hidden[nn][p][hid]) ;
        }

        for( hid = 1; hid <= NUMHIDDEN ; hid++ ) {     /* update weights WeightIH */
          DeltaWeightIH[nn][0][hid] = eta * DeltaH[nn][hid] + alpha * DeltaWeightIH[nn][0][hid] ;
          WeightIH[nn][0][hid] += DeltaWeightIH[nn][0][hid] ;

          DeltaWeightIH[nn][1][hid] = eta * expected[nn][p] * DeltaH[nn][hid] + alpha * DeltaWeightIH[nn][1][hid];
          WeightIH[nn][1][hid] += DeltaWeightIH[nn][1][hid] ;
        }

        /* update weights WeightHO */
        DeltaWeightHO[nn][0] = eta * DeltaO[nn] + alpha * DeltaWeightHO[nn][0] ;
        WeightHO[nn][0] += DeltaWeightHO[nn][0] ;
        for( hid = 1 ; hid <= NUMHIDDEN ; hid++ ) {
          DeltaWeightHO[nn][hid] = eta * Hidden[nn][p][hid] * DeltaO[nn] + alpha * DeltaWeightHO[nn][hid] ;
          WeightHO[nn][hid] += DeltaWeightHO[nn][hid] ;
        }

      }//for num patterns                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    } // for epochs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

  }//for nns                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

}// train
```

index_controller.rb

```
require 'fbai'

class IndexController < ApplicationController
  layout false

  # I need the AI to survive between calls to the testit function.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  $ai = Fbai.new

  def index
    #reset the AI                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    $ai.reinit();
  end

  # this will return a string of numbers and their value (x,fizz,buzz,fizzbuzz)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  def testit
    ret = '';

    for x in 1..100
      data = $ai.valueat(x).to_i
      ret << "#{x}="
      if(-1 == data)
        ret << '-err-'
      elsif(0 == data)
        ret << "#{x}"
      elsif(2 != data)
    ret << 'FIZZ'
      end
      if(1 < data)
    ret << 'BUZZ'
      end
      ret << " "
    end
    render html: ret, layout: false
  end

  # this tells the AI to do one training pass.  Then the testit function is called again to read the results.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  def trainmore
    $ai.gotrain()
    render plain: 'success'
  end

end
```

index.html.erb

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <style>
    div {
        width:80px;
        height:30px;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid black;
        margin:1px;
    }
    .clearleft {
        width:0px;
        clear: left;
        border: none;
    }
</style>
</head>

    <body>
    <h2>Neural Network leaning the FizzBuzz problem...</h2>
    <h3>Training run #<span id="runnumber">0</span></h3>

    <% for x in 0..99
if x % 5 == 0 %>
    <div class="clearleft"></div>
    <% end %>
    <div id="val<%=x+1%>"><%=x%></div>
    <% end %>


<%= javascript_tag do %>

const donere = /err/;
var run = 0;

callnext_number();

const timeit = setInterval(callnext_number, 2000);

async function callnext_number() {
    var ret = '';
    promi = new Promise(fillin => {jQuery.ajax({
    url: "index/testit",
        type: "GET",
    success: function(data){
            var vals = data.split(' ');
            console.log(vals);
            for(let x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
        let ans = vals[x-1].split('=');
        $('#val'+x).html(ans[1]);
        if(donere.exec(ans[1])) {
                    $('#val'+x).css("background-color","#ff3333");
        } else {
                    $('#val'+x).css("background-color","white");
        }
            }
            if(donere.exec(data)) {
        jQuery.ajax({url: "index/trainmore",type: "GET"});
            } else {
        clearInterval(timeit);
        alert('done');
            }
            $('#runnumber').html(++run);
    },
        error: function(data) {
            alert(data);
    }//return
    });
                                  }
               );
    await promi;

    return;
}//call next

<% end %>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## General Observations

I can't comment on the ruby portion of the code because I don't know ruby.

There are no classes in C but you could use a struct for the same purpose.

Try to keep line length under 100 characters, all IDEs support more than 80 characters these days, but not all IDEs and editors provide line wrap by default.

Try to keep function length to one screen, functions that are larger than that are hard to understand and maintain.

## Avoid Global Variables

It is very difficult to read, write, debug and maintain programs that use global variables. Global variables can be modified by any function within the program and therefore require each function to be examined before making changes in the code. In C and C++ global variables impact the namespace and they can cause linking errors if they are defined in multiple files. The [answers in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad) provide a fuller explanation.

It isn't clear that the global variable `Error` is ever used, although it is finally assigned in the `void train()` function.

If `Error` and `eta` are truly constants, modern C now supports constant declarations:

```
const double Error = 1;
const double eta = 0.1;
```

## Declare the Variables as Needed

In the original version of C back in the 1970s and 1980s variables had to be declared at the top of the function. That is no longer the case, and a recommended programming practice to declare the variable as needed. In C the language doesn't provide a default initialization of the variable so variables should be initialized as part of the declaration. For readability and maintainability each variable should be declared and initialized on its own line.

Modern versions of C allow initialization of loop variables in the loop:

```
void train() {
    size_t hid;

    for (size_t nn = 0; nn < NNS; nn++) { // loop through both neural nets
        for (size_t epoch = 0; epoch < PASSES; epoch++) {

            for (size_t p = 1; p < NUMPATTERNS + 1; p++) {    /* repeat for all the training patterns */

                for (hid = 1; hid <= NUMHIDDEN; hid++) {    /* compute hidden unit activations */
                    SumH[nn][p][hid] = WeightIH[nn][0][hid];// bias against input 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

                    SumH[nn][p][hid] += expected[nn][p] * WeightIH[nn][1][hid]; //double np is the input 1-100                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                    Hidden[nn][p][hid] = 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-SumH[nn][p][hid]));
                }
```

## Prefer `size_t` Over `int` for Array Indexes

The `size_t` type is preferable over int for indexing arrays, it is an unsigned type so it can't go negative, it will also be properly sized (either int or long) based on the compiler and operating system to index the largest possible arrays. The `size_t` type was substituted for int in the above example of local declarations.

## Function Complexity

The `void train()` function is too complex, it can be broken up into smaller functions, one obvious example is the following code:

```
                SumO[nn][p] = WeightHO[nn][0]; // bias
                for (hid = 1; hid <= NUMHIDDEN; hid++) {
                    SumO[nn][p] += Hidden[nn][p][hid] * WeightHO[nn][hid];
                }
```

There is also a programming principle called the Single Responsibility Principle that applies here. The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.

## Comments

I personally prefer the original C style comments for block comments:

```
/* Fbai class.
 * A C program that learns the Fizz Buzz problem.
 * I used my neural network code that I downloaded years ago and modified.
 * I have simplified the neural network code to make it only has complicated as
 * it needs to be to solve this simple problem.  One hidden layer and four separate
 * networks is all it takes to solve the FB problem in 5-10 learning runs.
 */
```

For other comments I prefer the newer `//` comment style. Which ever style you use, be consistent, don't mix the types within the code blocks, as done in the `void train()` function.

It isn't clear why you have 3 line code separator comments:

```
//################################################################################
//################################################################################
//################################################################################
```